# Merge adapter with different layout managers

Tags: android, android-mergeadapter

I am using [MergeAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter) to combine 2 adapters It works fine .

Problem is for 1 adapter I need LinearLayoutManager with single column and for second adapter I need GridLayoutManager to show items in 2 columns . Is there any way to do it ?

I found a working solution(added below) by setting it to `GridLayoutManager` and span size based on position . I just want to know is there a better way to do this .

Answer (score 2):

Set `GridLayoutManager` to `RecyclerView` and span size based on position .

```
   val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
   layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                    if(position==0){
                        return 2  //no of colums it show occupy
                    }
                    return  1
                }
            }
   recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

In this case if position in mergeadapter is 0 then the only 1 column will be show come else 2 columns will be shown .

Comment: When you say, position in MergeAdapter, you are saying for example if MergeAdapter has 3 adapters, the position 0 is for the first adapter, 1 for the second and 2 for the thirth right ? that position is not the position of the items inside each adapter

Comment: I remember it being position of the items . if 1st adapter has 10 items then position 2 will be 3rd item in first adapter